# How do I run Munin plugins written in Ruby, using RVM?

Tags: ruby, munin, rvm

I try to run some Munin plugins written in Ruby. I would like to use RVM, so Munin needs to know where to find Ruby. I tried to change the line calling munin-cron in the cron file as follows:

```
*/5 * * * *     munin bash -c 'source /usr/local/lib/rvm && rvm 1.9.2@munin && /usr/bin/munin-cron'
```

This leads to error messages in munin-node.log, saying

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

When I change the plugins' shebangs to the actual path of the Ruby executable it works, but the RVM environment should be set so that '/usr/bin/env ruby' works. It does when I execute the plugins as root.

Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Since Munin seems to reset the environment when executing the plugins, I tried to set the plugins' shebangs to the RVM wrapper script, I created with

```
rvm wrapper 1.9.2@munin munin
```

Now I get several "command not found" errors on variable names, implying that the plugins now are interpreted by the shell instead of Ruby.

**Update 2**

Copying the wrapper script instead of the symlink rvm creates and adding

```
source /usr/local/lib/rvm
```

doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Forget everything I did so far, trying to make this work. After creating the wrapper script with

```
rvm wrapper 1.9.2@munin munin
```

I only had to add the *command* attribute to the configuration of the plugin in question in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node:

```
[my_plugin]
group rvm
command /usr/local/rvm/bin/munin_ruby %c
```

Now I can use my munin gemset or create a separate gemset for each plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, `env` is being called with the argument `ruby`, but it can't find anything called ruby to execute.  That means when env runs, the path is not set up correctly to find the ruby executable.  I assume that is configured in /usr/local/lib/rvm.  Try running it outside of the cronjob, does it work?  For example:

```
bash -c 'source /usr/local/lib/rvm rvm 1.9.2@munin && /usr/bin/munin-cron'
```

Try also calling bash with the -x argument so it outputs all commands to stderr as it executes them (`bash -xc 'blah'`).  That should help you figure out where things are going wrong.

Grep through /usr/local/lib/rvm and see where it's calling env, and then work back from there to determine why the $PATH is not set correctly when env is called.

Comment: Good hint with the -x flag. It shows that the environment is set up correctly. Munin seems to reset it when executing the plugins.